# Stored Procedures doesn't show up in MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL database which has a few stored procedures, functions, and tables.

The problem I face is when I try to load the MySQL Database in MySQL WorkBench 6.3, it shows only Tables. Views, Stored Procedures, Triggers, and functions are not visible.

When I searched online for this, a few people suggested changing the value of lower_case_table_names to 1. I did that too, but still, it doesn't load any stored procedures or functions.

One more thing: I tried to connect to the same MySQL database using SQLYog. There it shows all the stored procedures and functions. Can anyone tell me the reason for this cause and a possible fix?

Here are the screenshots of MySQL Workbench and SQL Yog respectively.

[image: mysql workbench]

[image: sql yog]

Comment: It sounds like the account needs to be [Granted SHOW VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) on the applicable schemas. Give that a simple try, grant the account **SHOW VIEW** and this can be done via MySQL Workbench too; **Object Rights** | select **SHOW VIEW**.

Comment: Hi @PimpJuiceIT, Thanks for replying. I have tried what you suggested, looks like the Show View in Object Rights is already selected. Any other solution?

Comment: Perhaps one of these answers will help you.... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95529/mysql-workbench-not-showing-stored-procedures-that-i-have-created

Comment: I have already tried with those solutions. None of them work for me. Actually, I'm using SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant) to migrate from MySQL to MS SQL and even in the tool (SSMA) it doesn't show stored procedures, functions, etc. So I thought might be if we fix it on the MySQL workbench that will help the tool too. As the tool (SSMA) and the MySQL workbench are behaving in the same manner.

Comment: That's interesting I've never migrated from MySQL to MS SQL but I know both technologies for sure. It'd be interesting hear about success with stored procedure logic such as `TOP #` vs `LIMIT #` and those type differences in the SQL logic MySQL uses and T-SQL, functions, etc. I know with MS SQL SSMS you can `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION` to be able to see SPs populate in the explorer pane or whatever.

Comment: I wonder if you cannot see those because those are objects it cannot migrate per differences with MySQL logic versus MS SQL Server T-SQL logic.I'd get a "test" migration server setup if possible and then do testing from there before you say bye-bye to the production MySQL environment though. You might have to rewrite the stored procedures but I'm interested in hearing your solution and how it goes when you get it completed.

Comment: Sure mate. I have read online that the SSMA does a great job to migrate complete data including stored procedures, triggers, and stuff. But I don't know why it doesn't show. You mentioned something about GRANT VIEW DEFINITION what is that? Will that help me to display the procedures? Sorry for asking such lame questions, noob in these databases stuff.